# Is this a bug or what idk what happenned but visual studio deleted all of my designs on my form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]Is this a bug or what idk what happenned but visual studio deleted all of my designs on my form.
In my form i had some textbox and some buttons and when i launched today i was editing the design of the form and they just got disappeared now i can only see my background of the form nothing else every thing else is deleted or reseted idk.
Also when i click on the Form Design code i can see the code for those textbox and buttons but i cannot see the actual textbox and buttons on the form even if i run it!
Any one i would like some help.
Thanks.

Comment: Try: Close Visual Studio, delete the /bin, /obj and /.vs folders from your project, then reopen Visual Studio and reopen the project and see if it works. If not, then that's what source control is for!

Comment: thanks but that didnt work!

Comment: If you open up the document outline (View > Other Windows > Document Outline), what happens when you drill down and select one of the controls that disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

You can check ".Designer.cs" whether the .add statement of each control added to the window still exists. If it does not exist, you can add it manually.

Figure 1:

[image: here]

Figure 2:

[image: As follows:]

Comment: Is your problem solved? If not, you can check whether InitializeComponent(); is normal.

Comment: i am not sure i know where to find  "InitializeComponent();"

Comment: You can open Design.cs, click ‘+’, as shown in Figure 1, then you will find InitializeComponent().

Comment: You can check whether the code similar to Figure 2 exists in 'InitializeComponent()'. If it does not exist, you can add it manually.